# How to use functions from another component in React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have two components, one for API and another for UI. I am trying to access a function from API Component in UI component like below,

```
import APIComponent "./APIComponent";
APIComponent.getData().(response:any) => { //showing error here as "Property 'getData' does not exist on type '{ APIComponent: () => any; }'"
    console.log(response);
  })
```

Below is my APIComponent,

```
const APIComponent=():any=>{
const getData=():any =>{
//forming request
}
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should export them first, without an default export, so that would be

```
export const APIComponent=():any=>{}
export const getData=():any =>{}
```

Then try to import them

```
import {getData} "./APIComponent";
```

or try to export default and object and in that object add the functions as methods like so

```
export const APIComponent = () => {};
const getData = () => {
  alert("Getting the data");
};
export default {
  getData
};
```

Then you can actually export them and import them without the Destructure Syntax

```
import APIComponent from "./APIComponent"

   APIComponent.getData();
```

Have a look at this Sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-feather-9z24o?file=/src/App.js